# Running VS-Code / X11 from headless linux server without Gnome/KDE

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run vs-code on a remote headless Linux box, and display via X11 to a local X server (mobaXterm in a Windows box).

I can ssh into the linux box, set DISPLAY environment variable, and run other X applications successfully (e.g. xterm) and see the windows pop up locally on my desktop.

When I run `code --verbose .` on the linux host, it is connecting to the X11 server (I get the auth popups from mobaXterm) but code won't start.

```
[main 13:28:20] Resolving machine identifier...
[main 13:28:20] Resolved machine identifier: 2224e9b825fd9e11bdab87672d9f6cc2278c1cf137ff0d4fa5a7ef84650999e7
[main 13:28:20] update#setState idle
xdg-settings: unknown desktop environment
[main 13:28:20] windowsManager#open
```

and code just exits.  This seems to be related to attempts to find Gnome/KDE environments, but I'm not running those, mobaXterm has it's own Windows-integrated WM.

Is it possible to run VS Code remotely via X11 ?